# #VALUE cells not updating formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, automatic-update, refresh

I am having an issue.

My formula works and comes up with #VALUE when it has no data ready for it to calculate. However, when data is put in for it to calculate it won't pick it up unless I delete the formula and retype it in. I don't change the formula at all but it suddenly allows for itself to work.

Here is the formula:

`=COUNTIFS('Data Input - All Students'!D$37:D$639,"*Writing*",'Data Input - All Students'!N$37:N$594,"PD 1 (i)")`

Things I've tried/checked

- File - Options - Formulas - Workbook  Calculations - Automatic
- Deleting and retyping formula (works.. but document is too big with too many formulas for this to be practical)

Comment: It would help people try to reproduce this and experiment with it if you would give an example of what you're doing that results in the ``#VALUE`` error.  Not the entire 2000-character formula, of course; just the part that causes the error.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article at [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60529&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) for the COUNTIFS function states:

> Important: Each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns as the criteria_range1 argument. The ranges do not have to be adjacent to each other.<

In your formula critera_range1 is `D$37:D$639` while your criteria_range2 is `N$37:N$594`.  Change criteria_range2 to `N$37:N$639` and the formula should work.

Comment: Good job!  I was just a little bit faster.

Comment: That fixed it!!! Thank you everyone so much. I did a quick find and replace and it all just automatically worked!! You guys are legends!

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling us the whole story, or at least not accurately. 
`COUNTIFS` counts the number of cells in criteria_range1
where criteria1 is true,
and where criteria2 is true for *the corresponding cell* in criteria_range2,
and so on (up to 127 range/criteria pairs). 
In order for the concept "the corresponding cell" to be meaningful / valid,
all the ranges must be the same dimensionality. 
This is stated in the documentation for `COUNTIFS`:

> **Important:**
>   Each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns
>   as the **criteria_range1** argument.

[here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) and [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/value-error-with-countifs-function/561c8a53-e948-4dae-8b23-b49f21f508b0).

You are using `COUNTIFS` on two ranges that are not the same size:

- `D$37:D$639` is 603 rows, and
- `N$37:N$594` is 558 rows.

That formula will ***never*** work.

My guess is that you have some other version of that formula,
where the two ranges *are* the same size, and when you "retype" the formula,
you are actually typing in the correct version.

---

P.S. I've been staring at this for the past half hour,
and I just noticed that the two ranges start in the same row
and end in different rows. 
So of course they are different numbers of rows long.